# What is a design matrix? How do I build a design matrix for Rasch analysis?

Tags: r, psychometrics, rasch

I am trying to do an LRSM Rasch analysis of 72-item data. This data has 67 binary items and 5 ternary items. I need to create a "design matrix" in order to analyze this data. I do not really know what a design matrix is, nor do I know how to create one for my data. Could someone please give me some clues on getting started?

Comment: A [design matrix](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22design+matrix%22) is also called a [model matrix](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22model+matrix%22). Follow the links to find hundreds of posts about them.

Answer (score 1):

Design matrix groups all your variables together, typically for regressions. If a variable is categorical, it'll be coded.

You can use `model.matrix` in R to construct one. However, you shouldn't need to do it yourself because whatever analysis you'll be using should automatically do it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! That tells me a lot.

It turns out I was having trouble due to using an improper analysis. So, I really did not need to construct one.